# How to create a realistic jelly sweet that is dusted with sugar?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

A sphere or hemisphere of jelly sweet would suffice.  Or a square? Whatever shape you decide. [image]

Comment: Depending on the required level of detail this should be quite simple. Loop Cut the default cube and shift it to the bottom then add a Sub Serv modifier. That should give you the shape. Then setup your base material and use a Noise Texture with a Color Ramp to create the sugar and Add the two together. The Color Ramp allows you to limit the range, so you go from TV static to just the whitest bits of TV static. We usually like users to post what they have tried so far.

Comment: Hi. What have you got so far? What have you tried? Where specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: Ray, I have started to learn node compositing only a few months ago. I keep scrapbooks of nodes: study purpose only. I collect screenshots of nodes for scrapbooks via Google Slides. This scrapbook example https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1ggss5H_XdWtIZ825iRuUjk7svvzdoPWM-cP1yv4kCCc/

Comment: A possible solution after modeling the base shape of the jelly candy is to give it a particle hair system and model the sugar as a single object of almost cube proportions. Weight paint the candy object and set it to use the sugar cube as a particle.

Comment: @Craig D Jones, I will experiment with particle hair system, when I get more skilled up in Blender.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mesh: Default Cube with single loop cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and the top **Face** scaled. With a **Subdivision Surface** modifier and **Smooth** shading.
Feel free to make this mesh a bit less "perfect".

[image]

Attempt 1: Just using materials.
[image]

Looks complicated but it can be broken down into simple areas.
The Far left **Object Info** and **ColorRamp** are just so any duplicated meshes get a random colour.

This leads into the base **Diffuse BSDF** which is mixed with a bit of transparency using the **Fresnel** as the factor.

Then the top set of nodes use the **Generated texture** coordinates through a **Noise Texture** (with quite a large **Scale**) into a constriction **ColorRamp**. If you play with the colour stops you change the pattern and distribution of "sugar". We then use a **Bump** node to create a **Normal** **Displacement** to give the "sugar" depth.

[image]

Attempt 2: Particle Emitter

Add another **Cube** (I have named mine "sugar") and setup the **particle emitter** settings for your sweet mesh.

[image]

I am opting to use an emitter not hair. The **End** is set to **1.0** so the particles are all created instantly. **Render Object** is set to "sugar". **Children** is **Simple** and size set to **0.25**. **Render** is set to **10** but you can tweak to increase the total rendered amount.
[image]

FYI I added an **Emitter Shader** to brighten them up this time.

There is lots of room for improvement but I hope this gets you started.

Comment: to enhance the brightness of particles you could also try adding a translucent shader to itself

Comment: Great answer. You are a star and many thanks.

Comment: @Nicola Sap, I will try that. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I tried zooming in on that material layout but it was too blurry to read. Any chance of a higher rez version?